# Importance of cucumber BDD tool

Tags: automated-testing, java, cucumber, bdd

I am working in selenium with page object pattern. I know the basic concepts of cucumber. Its a bdd tool and bdd is for customer verification acceptance test. Everyone can understand the gherkin syntax. There is no need of any technical.

My question is.. Why should I go for cucumber tool ?

As a tester have knowledge about selenium is enough for web application right?  What is the main importance using cucumber tool?  My seniors  told me that "make good knowledge in a particular tool". "Don't waste time to study other tool" .

Anybody please clear my doubt..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The importance of any [Behavior-driven development](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Behavior-driven_development) framework, methodology or tool is to communicate. Cucumber is primarily a tool to communicate requirements between the business people and the developer. Which can also function as automatable tests.

Cucumbers Gherkin could also be used to create a [DSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-specific_language) or predefined steps to let non technical testers also write automated tests without writing any code.

Adding an extra layer as BDD is not worth it if it is just a way developers write tests. Then it's just overhead. But it can be a very strong way to communicate acceptance criteria (requirements) with stakeholders and safeguard them automatically.

The [LeSS](https://less.works/) framework describes ["Specification by Example"](https://less.works/less/technical-excellence/specification-by-example.html) workshops where developers and business people come up with examples. Implementing these examples (or scenarios) with Gherkin after the workshops could be a structured way to document the new designed requirements.

Other reads:

- [Specification by Example](https://books.gojko.net/specification-by-example/) (book)

Answer (score 0):

> Why should I go for cucumber tool ? As a tester have knowledge about
>   selenium is enough for web application

- As you know it doesn't required technical background or knowledge
- If its requirement or high in priority then one can suggest to use Cucumber

> My seniors told me that "make good knowledge in a particular tool".
>   "Don't waste time to study other tool"

- Its totally depends on what and how you will get an opportunity.
- We can plan but current requirement & company interest we need to consider which matters the most
- For learning no one can bind you. Its always open opportunity for you. Can not predict when it will be in use for you

> Importance of Cucumber?

- You can figure it out simply by googling it

Comment: is it useful for a simple project or large ecommerce project ?  is it possible to convert the language to selenium code ?

Comment: yes you can. and Its dependent on convenience instead of project size friend.